# swift 3 ios tableview scroll by cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, tableview

I created a tableview and it works normally as intended. However, I would like to change the scrolling such a way where the user can only scroll one cell at a time so that, there is never a time where the cell is cut in half..

This is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIYGN.jpg

So basically i do not want the default scrolling.. i would like it to be scrolled one cell at a time to constantly remain with the view of the original state..

Is there a way?

Comment: In case you don't get a usable answer: The scrollView :didScroll, func ,is fired whenever the user scrolls down your table view (UITableView actually has a fixed height). And the UITableViewDelegate func, selectRowAtIndexPath, will move focus to a specific cell. I'm not going to take the time to figure out how to implement that func to do exactly what you need, but again, if you don't get a complete answer these methods are a starting point.

Comment: did you get your answer ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this ?

1. `scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:`?
2. `tableview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];`

Comment: urmm where do i put those exactly? sorry im kinda new to swift and programming

Comment: Perhap you can try `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` by set the indexPath parameter to increase row + 1 at a time. 

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorowatindexpath?language=objc

or use `scrollRectToVisible` while user scrolls the UITableView that you need to know the Cell Rect.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619439-scrollrecttovisible

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewWillTransition function for that to stop that issue..

```
verride func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){}
```