# How do I stop UITableview from scrolling more than one cell at a time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So each of my tableview cells are full screen height similar to tiktok, igtv etc. When the user is scrolling I want the tableview to stop at each cell, not be able to scroll once and go past 2/3 cells.

I am using a custom tableview cell programmatically and this is how I am currently implementing the tableview delegate and datasource functions

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(PostViewTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: PostViewTableCell.cellReuseIdentifier)
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.bounces = false
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return viewModel?.postInformations.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PostViewTableCell.cellReuseIdentifier) as? PostViewTableCell else {
        fatalError("Couldn't dequeue reusable cell")
    }
    cell.postViewCellOutput = self
    cell.setUpCell(position: indexPath.row, viewModel: viewModel)
    
 
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.frame.size.height
}
```

So I am calling canPlay on the cell to play the cell that is fully visible on the screen so it can start playing. I am using this method to check visibility:

```
private func checkIfCellIsVisible(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let cellRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
    return tableView.bounds.contains(cellRect)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swift 3 ios tableview scroll by cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712493/swift-3-ios-tableview-scroll-by-cell)

Comment: No I checked that question, they didn't have the solution

Comment: did you try the accepted answer? it does look right (although I didn't try)

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response. Here is how I solved it. I set:

```
  tableView.isScrollEnabled = false // Set the tableview scroll enabled to false
```

Then in the "cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath" function I saved the indexPath of the first row to the currentIndexPath property :

```
  currentIndexPath = indexPath
```

Then I added a gesture recognizer to the tableview for swiping up:

```
   let swipeToNextVideoGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
    #selector(swipeToNext(_:)))
    swipeToNextVideoGesture.direction = .up
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeToNextVideoGesture)
```

Then in the function I first checked if the next Row is in the tableview datasource array bounds, then I scrolled to that row:

```
    @objc private func swipeToNext(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let nextVideoIndexPath = currentIndexPath.row+1
    if !(nextVideoIndexPath >= viewModel.postInformations.count) {
        currentIndexPath = IndexPath(row: nextVideoIndexPath, section: indexPathSection)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: currentIndexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIScrollViewDelegate's `func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:)` on UITableViewDelegate since it is also a scroll view delegate to detect the end of drag and set the targetContentOffset to the row you want to, in this case the next row. For example:

```
var currIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let rect = tableview.rectForRow(at: self.currentIndexPath)
    targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
    self.currentIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.currentIndexPath.row+1, section: 0)
}
```

The advantage here is that the height of your rows is full screen and the dragging is thus ensured to end in the current displayed row. This wouldn't work properly if the row height is not full screen as you would see the scroll happen past several cells but ultimately end up going to the cell you want.

Comment: That doesn't work it still allows me to scroll once and it will continue scroll past the one cell.

Comment: It only work once when user lands on controller. When I scroll back to upper items, its not working.